# Качественный вывод страниц по id (GET запрос)

Tags: php, get

Собственно ни как не могу понять, как вывести качественно страницу по id, к примеру view?id=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']) {
 $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM  screen WHERE id = '.$id;
 $res = mysql_query($query);
 $news = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
 print_r($news);
 }
```

Comment: много буков

    if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'])

можно просто

    !empty( $_GET['id'] )